# TestNG like framework in C#

Tags: c#, java, testng

I am currently working on a project where I have to choose a framework for Automating C# test script. I already have done this using TestNG in Java. But for C# I haven't found proper framework yet. Is there any TestNG like framework in C#?

Answer (score 0):

I think that [MBUnit](http://www.mbunit.com/) could be the closest one, have a look, if I remember well, mbunit is supposed to be easy to extend, maybe you can fill the gaps with some efforts.

Comment: Thank you Felice for your answer.